# How are "Web Components" different from "jQueryUI"?

Tags: jquery-ui, web, web-component

While developing our own UI component libraries for Web and Mobile which one is more preferable - web component or jQueryUI?

Comment: This question is not for stackoverflow, try some other stack-exchange website...

Answer (score 2):

> How are “Web Components” different from “jQueryUI”?

They are very different by nature:

- Web Components are a set of HTML and DOM standards implemented in modern browsers.
- jQueryUI is a JS library which proposes some advanced UI controls.

> While developing our own UI component libraries for Web and Mobile which one is more preferable?

It... depends!

- If you have a team with jQuery skills, and you want to reuse lots of predefined controls, and build a cross-browser application, you could choose jQueryUI.
- If performance is your main concern, if you don't want to rely on 3rd party library/framework, you may want to use native Web Components.
- You can also use a mix: create Web Components that use internally jQueryUI controls.